# How to intercept get request in node.js express framework

Tags: node.js

I want to intercept static resource get request, and according to the user's device to return, here is what I have tried:

```
app.get("./css/common.css", function (req, res) {
    if (user_device_is_mobile) {
         // Send mobile version style
    } else {
         // Send desktop version style
    }
})
```

But the intercept seen doesn't work, so how can I make it work correctly?

Comment: did you try app.get("/css/common.css" also do you have app.use(express.static...) anywhere? You'd have to have your route before that I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is known as Content-Negotiation, you can google more about it.

But, to solve your problem why the intercept doesnt work is

```
app.get("/css/common.css", function (req, res) { ...
```

drop the **.** in front **/css**

you dont need . because you are referencing it as a URL and not the relative path of the file